# Issue in return of Image variable from django view (numpy array) to template

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, django-templates, django-views

I am a newbie in python/django/web development.

I am facing an issue with returning my image from my `django view` to my `django template`.

I have a dummy button on my HTML page which calls a function in my `views.py`. This function returns an image (which is in the form of a numpy array). I want to return the image to my template. Although, I am able to return the image variable without any error, in the template I am not being able to see the image.

This is the code in my `views.py` function which returns the image to the `dummy.html` page

```
def ipdtest(request, frameslug):
 import cv2
 frame= VTryON.objects.get(slug=frameslug)
 image_of_frame=frame.image.url
 frame_path=("path name"+str(image_of_frame))
 d=Frame_Superimposition()
 img=Frame_Superimposition.frameSuperimpose(d,frame_path)
 #print type(d)
 print type(img)
 #cv2.imshow('img', img)
 #cv2.waitKey(0)
 context={'d':d, 'img':img}
 return render_to_response('dummy.html',  context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The `img` variable is of the type `numpy array`. I know that the image is properly being processed since I am able to see it doing a `cv2.imshow`.

So is this a compatibility issue between numpy form and RGB form? If so, then how do I make the image display properly on to the `dummy.html`? This is how I retrieve it in  my dummy.html page.

```
<body class="body">
<div id="pageContainer">        
    <br>
      <img src="{{img}}" width=250 height=100/>
    <br>        
</div>
```

Please give some suggestions on how to solve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

What does `print img` statement print...? Anyways try this...

`{{ img.url }}`

Comment: The image is not actually saved anywhere in the server. Rather it is in main memory as a numpy array.